# lazy instantiation of the map value

Tags: groovy

Is there a way to instantiate the value of `map` lazy?

For example

```
class MapTest {
    @Lazy(soft = true) HashMap<String, List<String>> map
}
```

Doing like this I can use this call and get `null` without recieving `NullPointerException`

```
new MapTest().map.key1
```

However attempt to call

```
map.key1.remove(1)
```

will lead to `NullPointerException` due the `value` being `null`. (it would be fine if it threw `IndexOutOfBounds` exception)

Is there a way to instantiate the `list` value of the map?

Comment: What's `m` in your above example?

Comment: @tim_yates oh oh. Originally I instantiated `MapTest` as `MapTest m = new MapTest()`. Then I removed it for the example but `m` left

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try `map.withDefault` :

```
def map = [:].withDefault { [] }
assert map.key1.isEmpty()
```

Some explanation :

- [:] is the groovy way to instantiate an empty hash map
- `withDefault` is a groovy method on a map wich take a closure. this closure is call every time a key is requested to initialize the value if it doesn't exist. this closure take one parameter (the key) and should the value
- [] is the groovy way to create an empty list - { [] } is a closure wich return an empty list for every key

see others examples [here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.fr/2010/07/groovy-goodness-map-with-default-values.html)

Comment: Hm...But I have to instantiate `map` manually in that case, am I right?

Comment: you can write @Lazy def map = { [:].withDefault { [] } }

Comment: But will it initialize `map` on the spot or when it will be required? I mean won't it override the default `Lazy` behavior?

Comment: no, it will be instanciated on the first access. http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/lang/Lazy.html