# For-comprehension or flatMap in groov/grails

Tags: scala, grails, groovy, grails-controller

Since grails 2.3, there is async/promise ability, like `task`, like `waitAll`. But once I have a handful of `promise`s, how to combine them?

For instance, in a controller

```
def nameT = task { database1.getNameById(345L) }
def balanceT = task { database2.getBalanceById(456L) }
render nameBalanceView([name: nameT.get(), balance: balanceT.get()])
```

But now we need to block waiting on both `get`.
Is it possible to have the last `render` line in form of

```
task { render nameBalanceView([name: name, balance: balance]) }
```

To compare, Scala can do it like this:

```
Action.async {
   val nameF = Future { database1.getNameById(345L) }
   val balanceF = Future { database2.getNameById(456L) }
   val nameAndBalanceF = nameF flatMap { n => balanceF map { b => (n, b) } }
   nameAndBalance map { nb => nameBalanceView(nb) }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. In order to render your view it needs a model, and your model consists two domain instances. It doesn't matter which task completes first because the model is incomplete until *both* tasks finish. So there's no way for the view to get a head start. Having said that, since the model is a Map, what you may be able to do is use a lazy map that would call `task.get()` when a key is requested. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243302/lazy-instantiation-of-the-map-value

Comment: According to Async Response Rendering doc http://docs.grails.org/2.3.11/guide/async.html one should be able to have full-async without explicit call `get`. I'd like to know if it is possible to have the framework to handle all the blocking, like in Scala/Play.